# Android navigation drawer setcheckable

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hello Greetings to everyone .I have Developed one app,in that app i have implemented navigation drawer and set 
inside menu file

group `android:checkableBehavior="single"`

First menu is Home which is default.So the problem is that when i click on second or third menu it open respective fragment but when i press back button it r=open home fragment but in navigation drawer checkable item is last selected

On Back button last checkable item is checkable but it open home fragment

Comment: post you layout please?

Comment: which layout sir........